# innerHTML not changing content of div after window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. It's meant to embed a YouTube video. However it seems that it somehow doesn't change the div that it's supposed to.

```
window.onload = embed;
function embed() {
    var apikey = "SNIP"; //Set to your API Key
    // See NOTEA below
    var channelName = "ThisWeekInScience"; //Set to your channel name
    var channelID = nameToID(channelName,apikey);
    //NOTEA: If you know it you can of course just comment that out and set the id manually.
    var video = checkLive(channelID,apikey);
    var autoplay = "1";
    if(video.length == 0) {
        video = archiveVideo(channelID,apikey);
        autoplay = "0";
    }
    var embedCode = "<object height=\"350\" width=\"425\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"https://www.youtube.com/v/" + video + "&autoplay=" + autoplay + "\"><embed height=\"350\" width=\"425\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/v/" + video + "&autoplay=" + autoplay + "\"></embed></object>";
    document.getElementById("liveembed").innerHTML = embedCode;
}
function nameToID(channelName,apikey) {
    var getChannelID = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getChannelID.open("GET","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=" + channelName + "&fields=items%2Fid&key=" + apikey,false);
    getChannelID.send();
    var channelIDobj = JSON.parse(getChannelID.responseText);
    return channelIDobj.items[0].id;
}
function checkLive(channelID,apikey) {
    // In future check if soon live and refresh until live
    var getLive = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getLive.open("GET","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId=" + channelID + "&eventType=live&maxResults=1&type=video&fields=items%2Fid&key=" + apikey,false);
    getLive.send();
    var liveVideo = JSON.parse(getLive.responseText);
    if(liveVideo.items[0] === undefined) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return liveVideo.items[0].id.videoId;
    }
}
function archiveVideo(channelID,apikey) {
    var getPlaylist = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getPlaylist.open("GET","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=" + channelID + "&fields=items%2FcontentDetails&key=" + apikey,false);
    getPlaylist.send();
    var playlistObj = JSON.parse(getPlaylist.responseText);
    var playlistID = playlistObj.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
    var getArchiveVideo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getArchiveVideo.open("GET","https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=" + playlistID + "&fields=items%2FcontentDetails&key=" + apikey,false);
    getArchiveVideo.send();
    var archiveVideoObj = JSON.parse(getArchiveVideo.responseText);
    return archiveVideoObj.items[0].contentDetails.videoId;
}
```

I am not able to use HTML5 due to the theme I use in WordPress using xhtml transitional. I also want to have this be as portable as possible and therefore don't want to use jQuery nor other libraries.

The current version of it is at http://www.twis.org/live/
I also have a version running at https://scienceisland.org/science-island-chat/

Comment: not sure it its related, but I get a syntax error on that page you gave as an example. FYI.

Comment: Yeah, it appears there is malformed javascript on your page which could be preventing this from executing.  Look in your console when you load the page.

Comment: I added another site it's running at, where it does embed, and fixed the syntax error(s). It's still not working right.

Comment: Just so others know, I've posted this for all to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/youtubeliveembed/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that having a window.onload in the page was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to contains JavaScript errors.

```
jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'cyclic': false,
    'autoScale': false,
    'padding': ,
    'opacity': false,
```

The padding has no value.  Remove that line, or give it a value according to fancybox documentation.